# Java Regex Date Replace From Text

Tags: java, regex, date, replaceall

I have googled to find my answer but can't able to get one. Since I am very novice in Regular Expressions. I need to put my question here.

I have a text file in which I need to replace the contents having date value in `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"` format.

Sample Contents:

```
<td> Order is Placed on:</td>
<td>The date and time is 12/08/2013 05:46:56 PM</td>
```

I need resulted output by replacing only the date value. Something like:

```
<td> Order is Placed on:</td>
<td>The date and time is </td>
```

**This date value can be appeared at any place. There is no specific suffix or prefix occurring around it.**

What can be the regex for above expected result in below code:

```
String textLine = readline.replaceAll("some_regex","");
```

Thank you.

---

**The solution is :**

```
String textLine = readline.replaceAll("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s(?:AM|PM)", "");
```

**Thank you - @Antoniossss**

Comment: The date pattern is `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a`. You know what values all those identifiers can take, just convert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REGEX:

```
\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s(?:AM|PM)
```

This matches the general pattern, but will accept non-valid dates, which doesn't seem to be a concern for you.

Comment: What about `99/99/9999 99:99:99 PM`? Is that a valid date?

Comment: OA said nothing bout capturing valid dates. He provided example, I provided solution.

Comment: Thank you @Antoniossss I only needed a pattern to match. It has nothing to do with validating a date. your solution works great.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use a backslash before the regex symbols:

```
    String pattern = "\\d{2}";
```

Explaining the used symbols in Antoniossss answer:

- \d    Any digit, short for [0-9]
- \s    A whitespace character
- {X}    Occurs X number of times, {} describes the order of the preceding liberal

> *e.g.*: \d{2} searches for two digits
>
> X|Z    Finds X or Z.
>
> For learning more about regular expressions in Java, I can recommend you the following tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a short expression which checks for a starting digit and two word characters:

```
"\\d+.+\\d+.\\w{2}"
```

I use [rubular.com](http://rubular.com) to check my regex.